# finish() method is not working inside of AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-asynctask, android-activity

I know finish() method is used to finish current activity while starting a new activity. But probably finish() method is not working in my AsyncTask override method.
Okay, My current activity is **LoginActivity** in which I implemented AsyncTask and in one of my override methods of AsyncTask  I am starting **LoggedInActivity**. In **LoggedInActivity** there are many fragments. This doesn't cause any problem I think so. When I press BACK button I get **LoginActivity**. I don't want that. Please take a look at my code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private void startLoggedInActivity()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, LoggedInActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    private class FetchProfileTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject>
    {
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... strings) {
            bla....bla....
        }
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            bla....bla....
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            try {
                startLoggedInActivity();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("Exception", "FetchProfileTask - onPostExecute()");
            } finally {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I will be pleased if anyone helps me.....

Comment: why don't yout try finishing your activity in onPostExecute() after starting the loggenInActivity

Comment: @dcharms If I use `android:noHistory="true"` this will be applicable for all activity starting from **LoginActivity**. I don't want that. I want to finish **LoginActivity** for some specific activities.

Comment: @MahmoudElmorabea Please take a look at `startLoggedInActivity()` method. I used `finish()` to finish current activity. But don't know why it's not working.

Comment: check your method signature, onPostExecute() return void and can't return a JSONObject

Comment: @MahmoudElmorabea thanks. you notice it. In my app code it is **void**. It happens in stackoverflow editor somehow. I edited.

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:noHistory="true"` to LoginActivity in your manifest.

What this does is mark the activity to not be added to your Activity stack after going to another activity. So when you press the back button, it will close your app rather than going back to the LoginActivity. With this approach, you no longer need the `finish()` call.

```
<activity
    ...
    android:noHistory="true">
```

Comment: If I use `android:noHistory="true"` this will be applicable for all activity starting from **LoginActivity**. I don't want that. I want to finish **LoginActivity** for some specific activities.

Comment: Under what circumstances would you like to go back to the LoginActivity? To me, it would only make sense if you log out, which you can then use `startActivity` to bring the LoginActivity back up.

Comment: No no no. In my app I need to start various activities from **LoginActivity** and I need to finish **LoginActivity** when it starts only **LoggedInActivity**.

Comment: You could start LoggedInActivity with the new task flags on the intent so that it makes it the root Activity. Would that accomplish what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The back button will change to the last activity. If the activity is finished, Android will create it again(I'm not very sure).So I think you can rewrite the back button.

Answer (score 0):

```
Activity activity; // Instance Variable
```

Inside On Create  :

```
activity = this;

private void startLoggedInActivity()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, LoggedInActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    activity.finish();
}
```

Comment: What is the different between your code and my code ?

Comment: the difference is that activity.finish() access to the parent context activity and executes this method, otherwise you will need to finish the activity using runOnUI() thread, to finish the activity in the correct thread. Regards

Comment: @JSanchez `onPostExecute` *is* run on the main UI thread. There is no difference in this code.